# Select retornando datas no objeto diferentes do que está registrado no banco MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, select

Estou com um problema quando listo o conteúdo de uma tabela e armazeno em uma lista a data está com um dia a menos.

Já pesquisei bastante pela web e não encontrei uma solução para o problema.

Abaixo o método de cadastro:

```
public String cadastrarPeriodo(LocalDate dataInicio, LocalDate dataFim) throws SQLException {
    String message = null;

    Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getConexaoMySQL();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(inserirPeriodoBancoHora);
        stmt.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(dataInicio));
        stmt.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(dataFim));

        int res = stmt.executeUpdate();

        if(res == 1){
            message = "Dados Registrados com Sucesso!";
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        message = "Erro ao Salvar os Dados";
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }

    return message;
}
```

Método de pesquisa

```
public List<PeriodoBancoHora> listarPeriodosCadastrados() throws SQLException {
    List<PeriodoBancoHora> listaPeriodoBancoHora = new ArrayList<PeriodoBancoHora>();

    Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getConexaoMySQL();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(listarPeriodosCadastrados);

        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(res.next()){
            do {
                PeriodoBancoHora periodoBancoHora = new PeriodoBancoHora();
                periodoBancoHora.setIdPeriodoBancoHora(res.getInt(1));
                periodoBancoHora.setDataInicio(res.getDate(2).toLocalDate());
                periodoBancoHora.setDataFim(res.getDate(3).toLocalDate());
                listaPeriodoBancoHora.add(periodoBancoHora);
            } while (res.next());
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }

    return listaPeriodoBancoHora;
}
```

No banco de dados está registrando o valor que estou informando na tela, porem o valor retornado está subtraindo 1 dia, conforme as imagens abaixo:
[image: Imagem que mostra o retorno do banco em tela]

[image: Informação da forma como está registrada em banco]

[image: Estrutura da Tabela no MySQL]

O conector do MySQL que estou utilizando é mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar.

Desde já agradeço.

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Tive um problema parecido com esse com o SQL Server e foi só trocar o drive. Ve a compatibildiade do drive com a versão do MySQL que você esta usando Ou veja também o Tipo de Data que está sendo utilizada no Java vs o tipo Date do MySQL

Comment: rLinhares, obrigado pelo retorno, atualizei o driver, porém o que resolveu o problema foi uma configuração na conexão.
MySQL é bem chato com algumas configurações, para fazer a conexão a primeira vez tive de setar o timezone na connectionfactory, e peguei um padrão UTC, foi somente alterar para America\Sao_Paulo que passou a funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obrigado pelo retorno, consegui resolver o problema, somando as dicas aqui recebidas.
Primeiro a indicação do Krismorte, me levou ao entendimento de que meu problema estava ligado ao timezone, pesquisei como ajustar o timezone no banco de dados, outras formas de aplicar a configuração sugerida, porem nada funcionou.
Depois o rLinhares indicou a atualização do driver de conexão, o fiz e o problema persistiu, foi então que pesquisei sobre como entrar com o timezone direto na string de conexão do banco e para minha surpresa, já havia uma configuração de timezone=UTC que alterei para timezone=America\Sao_Paulo.

E passou a retornar o valor corretamente.

Obrigado pelo apoio de todos e fica aí as opções para quem enfrentar problemas semelhantes.

Answer (score 0):

substitui essa linha:

```
res.getDate(2).toLocalDate()
```

por:

```
res.getDate(2).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/4722804

Comment: Krismorte,

Obrigado pelo retorno, ao alterar a linha conforme indicado, ocorre o exception Unsupported Operation.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.sql.Date.toInstant(Date.java:304)
 at br.com.qualytratus.ControleQualy.DAO.PeriodoBancoHoraDAO.listarPeriodosCadastrados(PeriodoBancoHoraDAO.java:122)
 at br.com.qualytratus.ControleQualy.view.PeriodoBancoHoras.listarPeriodos(PeriodoBancoHoras.java:78)

Tentei alterar o timezone em outros momentos, mas ainda não resolveu.